# How to set a TTL for all items in a MapState in Flink?

Tags: join, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to clean up all entries in a `MapState` at a given timestamp.

I am considering two ways to do:

1. Hold the `cleanup timestamp` in a `ValueState`, Register a timer for the `cleanup timestamp`, When the timer fires clear the `MapState`. Though the `cleanup timestamp` might be the same, this would happen for every item added to the `MapState`. I am relying on Flink de-duping the timers.
2. Calculate the TTL based on (`cleanup timestamp` - `current timestamp`), use `StateTtlConfig` to set a TTL for the `MapState`

Which is a better approach (performance, accuracy etc.)?
Does StateTtlConfig work for even time processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to clear out all entries in the `MapState` at the same time, then I would not use `StateTtlConfig`, since Flink will spend 8 bytes to store a timer with each map entry. This is a lot of unnecessary storage overhead.

With `StateTtlConfig`, the state expiry can only be specified in terms of processing time.

Also keep in mind that `StateTtlConfig` cannot be added to, or removed from, an existing state descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to clean all records at given timestamp, then option 1 should be more performant definetely. In general using TTL on flink state will add additional overhead, since it will be checked every time key in `MapState` is accessed. It depends on how do You exactly use the state(how many records do You plan to store there, how often will You access it and the type of the state), but I'd say that if You just want to drop all records at given timestamp then option 1 is better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think use timerService to register  a timer  gives you better performance.but  event-time timers only fire with watermarks coming in, you may also schedule and coalesce these timers with the next watermark by using the current one.

```
val coalescedTime = ctx.timerService.currentWatermark + 1
ctx.timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(coalescedTime)
```